# Android Background Animation Lagging Game

Tags: android, animation, background, android-animation, android-resources

I tested setting an ImageView as a animation-list with some smaller png files and there was no problem, but trying this out for the background of the RelativeLayout works, but causes some serious lagging.  This has been happening when I use the first 5 out of 16 png images and I noticed that it won't run if I add all of them due to memory out of bounds.  Here's the relevant code (onFinish() is just when the countdown timer stops): 
Main Method:

```
@Override
    public void onFinish() {
        count.setText("Go!");
        playing = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        score.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Start background animation
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rl.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
```

The layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Animation-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_0" android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_1" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_1" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_2" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_3" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_4" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_5" android:duration="50" />

</animation-list>
```

And here's some of the images in question in case there's something wrong with them https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYCUt.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried moving all of the relevant images/pngs into a

> drawable-nodpi

folder inside of your res folder?

Comment: I haven't tried that, and after googling 'nodpi' it seems like it then 'does not scale resources tagged with this'.  Wouldn't that cause problems on screens of different sizes? I'm fairly new to android development so I'm not sure.

Comment: Just tried it, that worked! No more lagging.  Mind explaining what was going on? I'm not sure I understand what happened

Comment: I'm no expert myself, but I know Android is capable of doing a lot of elaborate memory optimization depending on the size of the images in question, and the size of the views they will be displayed in. My understanding is placing your images in this folder will bypass all of Androids techniques. It may help you now, but keep it in mind if memory issues go awry later on.